# Exercise with string

Tags: c++

I have a problem with an exercise I found here [exercise 3](https://erlerobotics.gitbooks.io/erle-robotics-cpp-gitbook/object-oriented_programming__oop_and_inheritance/exercises_oop.html). I report it here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class Animal
{
    protected:
     int age;
     char name[10];
    public:
     void set_data (int a, char b[10]) // the set data is inherited by here to the two classes Zebra and Dolphin
     {
        age = a;
        strcpy(b,name);

     }
};

class Zebra:public Animal
{
    public:

    void message_zebra() {
        cout<< "The zebra named "<< name <<" is "<< age << " years old. The zebra comes from Africa. \n";
        }
};

class Dolphin: public Animal
{
    public:

    void message_dolphin() {
        cout<< "The dolphin named "<< name << " is "<<age << " years old. The dolphin comes from New Zeland.\n";
        }
};


int main ()
{
    Zebra zeb;
    Dolphin dol;
    char n1[10] = "Max";
    char n2[10] = "John";

    zeb.set_data (5,n1); 
    dol.set_data (2,n2);

    zeb.message_zebra() ;
    dol.message_dolphin() ;

    return 0;
}
```

In principle, I have two base classes that inherit the proprieties of the class `Animal` but when I run it in the main, I can't be able to display the correct name of the two animals.

Comment: By the way: You should use `std::string` instead of character arrays.

Comment: How are you not able to display the correct names? Do you get a compilation error, do you get a run time error or does it produce an unexpected result? If you get an error, what is that error? If you get an unexpected result, what where you expecting and how does the observed behavior differ from your expectations?

Comment: If you change the prototype to `void set_data (int a, const char b[10])`, the compiler will provide a hint about where the problem is.

Comment: [A `std::strcpy` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy) should be helpful. Pay close attention to the order of the arguments!

Comment: When debugging a problem I find it helpful to create a minimal versions of the problematic program (better described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In your case the question boils down to "Why does `char n1[10] = "Max", char name[10]; strcopy(n1, name);` not update `name`?"

Comment: This is what happens when you copy destination to source

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of your specific bug (`strcpy()` argument order as commenters suggest), there are some issues both with the problem definition and your solution.

> Exercise 3
>
> Write a probram with a mother class animal. Inside it define a name and an age variables, and `set_value()` function. Then create two bases variables Zebra and Dolphin which write a message telling the age, the name and giving some extra information (e.g. place of origin).

The first thing we notice about this problem is that the wording is vague and unclear. What are "bases variables" anyway? Are you asked to subclass `Animal`? Who knows. As for the place of origin - is it the specific instance' origin, or the entire class'? And - is it the `Animal` class or the inheriting subclass? who knows.

Also, a `set_value()` member function is really quite an awful thing to have. Even if your members aren't public, you would still have a separate setter method for each field, e.g. `void setName(const std::string& name)`. Of course, it would be nicer to use a reference or a proxy for setting and getting a field, e.g. `std::string& name()` and `const std::string& name() const`.

Now, about your own code, note that the Zebra and Dolphin class don't really have a different behavior; and their "message" members print the same thing, except for the class name and the place of origin, which are different data. So why even bother with a subclass?

Also, it's not a good idea to use `char` arrays - use `std::string` unless there's a good reason not to. That way, you won't have an artificial limitation on the name length.